# Lenses for association list

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

There is `at` lens for `Map`/`HashMap`/etc in `Control.Lens.At`. But is any lens similar to `at` for association list type `[(k, v)]` (which is convertible to map)?

Comment: If you don't care about ordering and are okay dropping duplicate keys you can write a quick Iso: "myAList ^. Iso Map.fromList M.toList . at key"

Comment: And if you don't need to add or remove entries, then `traversed.itraversed :: IndexedTraversal' k [(k, v)] v` and you can use `index` to restrict that to a given key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of one that's provided for you, but `at` belongs to the typeclass `At`, so we could certainly write it ourselves. To avoid having to get our hands dirty with flexible (and possibly overlapping) instance extensions, we'll do this in a newtype.

```
newtype AList k v = AList [(k, v)]
```

First, we need a couple of family instances.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type instance IxValue (AList k v) = v
type instance Index (AList k v) = k
```

This just defines what the "key" and "value" is in our new type, which is straightforward. Now, we need to be able to read and write values at a specific key. Haskell already gives us a way to read values ([`Data.List.lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup)), but we have to make the writing function ourselves. Nothing fancy or lens-y here: just ordinary old Haskell filters and maps.

```
replaceAt :: Eq k => k -> Maybe v -> AList k v -> AList k v
replaceAt k Nothing (AList m) = AList $ filter (\(k', _) -> k /= k') m
replaceAt k (Just v) (AList m) =
    case lookup k m of
      Nothing ->
          -- Not present in the list; add it
          AList ((k, v) : m)
      Just _ ->
          -- Present; replace it
          AList $ map (\(k', v') -> if k == k' then (k', v) else (k', v')) m
```

Now we need to write the `At` instance, which depends on the `Ixed` instance. Fortunately, the lens library provides a default implementation for `Ixed` as long as we're implementing `At`, so the first instance declaration is simple.

```
instance Eq k => Ixed (AList k v)
```

Writing `at` is fairly straightforward as well. Just look at the types and follow your nose a bit, and the implementation you arrive at is the one we want.

```
instance Eq k => At (AList k v) where
    at k f (AList m) = fmap (\v' -> replaceAt k v' (AList m)) $ f (lookup k m)
```

And we're done. Now `at` will work for `AList`. If the newtype wrapper bothers you, you could pretty easily make a new function (`at'`, if you will) that does the newtype wrapping/unwrapping for you.

Proving that this instance satisfies the lens laws is left as an exercise to the reader.

**Complete code**

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Lens.At
import Data.List(lookup)

newtype AList k v = AList [(k, v)]

type instance IxValue (AList k v) = v
type instance Index (AList k v) = k

replaceAt :: Eq k => k -> Maybe v -> AList k v -> AList k v
replaceAt k Nothing (AList m) = AList $ filter (\(k', _) -> k /= k') m
replaceAt k (Just v) (AList m) =
    case lookup k m of
      Nothing ->
          -- Not present in the list; add it
          AList ((k, v) : m)
      Just _ ->
          -- Present; replace it
          AList $ map (\(k', v') -> if k == k' then (k', v) else (k', v')) m

-- Just take the default implementation here.
instance Eq k => Ixed (AList k v)

instance Eq k => At (AList k v) where
    at k f (AList m) = fmap (\v' -> replaceAt k v' (AList m)) $ f (lookup k m)
```